# Regex contains at least one uppercase letter AND NOT contains at least one underscore

Tags: regex, string, match, dispatcher, regular-language

I need a regex that contains at least one uppercase  and not contains any underscore, my current try out is:

```
(?=.*[A-Z_])
```

I tried string like : `example-chocolate-easter-egg-170g_349-85428671-ACCESSIBLEEASTEREGG`  ,  as this string contains `_` and at least one uppercase, so should be a false.  But my above regex still give true... it should be false...

Ideally , `example-chocolate-easter-egg-170g349-85428671-ACCESSIBLEEASTEREGG` ,  this is true as it does not contain `_` , contains at least one uppercase letter.

and this one should be false too, as it has no uppercase : `-chocolate-easter-egg-170g349-85428671-accessibleeasteregg`

Any suggestions? Regex code example would be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: You need `^[^A-Z_]+$`. Or, `^(?![^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?![^_]*_)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*_).+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/L0czmG/1).

Match a string that contains an uppercase character - `(?=.*[A-Z])`, does not contain underscore - `(?!.*_)`, and is not empty - `.+`. Remove `.+` or use `.*` to support empty input.

Comment: works perfectly, i have simplified it a bit , (?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*_)  it works too

Comment: Yes, you may remove ^ if you do not expect matching at the beginning of the text. Lookaheads checks are better done after ^, it is best practice.